# Datelist element in webform not working

Tags: webforms, datetime

I was just going through webform configurations and I changed the date list element format from default to raw. After doing this Im not able to add any element of type dateform to my webform and also not able to open the element configurations also. The error i get when clicked on element tab (refer the attached image) is "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

[image: Not able to go to the Configuration tab marked in red]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I created [Issue #3029964: Datelist element in webform not working](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3029964) in the Webform's issue queue.  Please try the provided patch.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in the latest Webform 8.x-5.x dev release.